# MacBook Pro crash - Sleep transition timed out AppleBCMWLANCore

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro 16 (2019) keeps crashing either when going to sleep or when waking up from sleep, when the power is disconnected and WiFi is on. Seems to be due to com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore.

I've confirmed that it does not crash when the power cable is kept plugged in, or when WiFi is turned off before closing the lid.

It is on macOS 10.15.7 (cannot update yet due to compatibility with some required software).

Is there a fix? I've tried NVRAM and SMC reset.

Crash log:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801a68ef7c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while calling power state change callbacks. Suspected bundle: com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore. Thread 0x5460d.
Backtracing specified thread
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff924fc9b900 : 0xffffff801a040848 
0xffffff820bcb3c40 : 0xffffff8019f3b4b1 
0xffffff820bcb3cb0 : 0xffffff8019f39cef 
0xffffff820bcb3d00 : 0xffffff801a03d949 
0xffffff820bcb3d40 : 0xffffff801a03d1ab 
0xffffff820bcb3d70 : 0xffffff801a62a028 
0xffffff820bcb3da0 : 0xffffff801a62cf39 
0xffffff820bcb3e00 : 0xffffff801a6122ca 
0xffffff820bcb3ea0 : 0xffffff801a611bf4 
0xffffff820bcb3ec0 : 0xffffff8019f5b5e5 
0xffffff820bcb3f40 : 0xffffff8019f5b111 
0xffffff820bcb3fa0 : 0xffffff8019ebf13e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19H114

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Nov 10 00:10:30 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: A477D537-F87E-3978-8D7F-A84B7C02E62E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000019c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8019e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8019d00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 15926231962029
last loaded kext at 15644410281101: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9dccb000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 3564386356385: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter    1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9c7f6000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.McAfee.driver.DlpUSB    1
com.crowdstrike.sensor  127.04
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.1.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.7
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.7
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.429
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMuxControl2  5.2.7
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.7
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    323.4
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.1.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!ASSE  1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: First test for any repeated panic is to eliminate any 3rd party kexts - com.McAfee.driver &
com.crowdstrike.sensor in this case. Though, if these are corporate installs, you'd be best speaking to your IT department. If they are user installs, then it might be best to not have two different 'antivirus' products installed together - they fight.

Comment: @Tetsujin Corporate installs unfortunately

Comment: Then best addressed to your IT department - esp *why* they have two 'antivirus' structures. That's never a good idea. (I'd perhaps hesitate slightly before wondering why anyone would use McAfee for anything, but that's my personal view on one particular structure & not really an 'inclusive' idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same issue for months and a solution that has bubbled up from various forums has been to turn off the Power Nap feature in both plugged in and Battery system pref panels.

[image]

Comment: I've been fighting this for a while on my 2015 Pro, although my crash references `com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport`. I'll try this and see if anything is improved, thanks!

Comment: it didn't work for me :( I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) on BigSur 11.6.3